# Omit a node on XmlSerializer.Serialize

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I have a class library provided by a third party, with a type in there called SaveAccount. When I try to serialize this class I get the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<SaveAccount xmlns="http://RiskBrowser/ExposureManager">
  <Body>
    <Token>JHSDUKJSHDKJ</Token>
    <JobId>2</JobId>
  </Body>
</SaveAccount>
```

What I need to do is strip out just the `<Body>` tags so I end up with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<SaveAccount xmlns="http://RiskBrowser/ExposureManager">
  <Token>JHSDUKJSHDKJ</Token>
  <JobId>2</JobId>
</SaveAccount>
```

Is there a nice way of doing this inside the XmlSerializer? Or another nice way someone can think of? I don't really want to start hacking around with the generated xml.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Body` is a public property (i.e. `SaveAccount` is not `IXmlSerializable`) and there are no other properties in `SaveAccount` to serialize, you can remove this node by serializing `Body` directly and applying XML serializer attribute overrides to rename and assign the correct namespace to the resulting element. Otherwise, you can create a custom XmlWriter and suppress this node on write.

Comment: Thanks this worked, although it feels a little "hacky". Still it's not exactly a normal situation. The library class is supposed to allow the generation of xml data consumed by the same third party app through a database insert (horrible I know). So they obviously didn't keep the public types in sync with whatever consumes them on their end.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, one way would be manipulating the `XML` after it has been generated to remove the `Body` node from it using `LINQ to XML` or `System.Xml`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was hoping to avoid having to do this. I thought there may be a way to override the default behavior of XmlSerializer to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Mark the type with the XmlIgnore attribute, like so:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public AType Body;
```

If you can't rebuild the third party library, you can use the XmlAttributeOverrides class to override the default way of serializing objects, something similar to:

```
XmlAttributes ignore = new XmlAttributes() { XmlIgnore = true};
XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
overrides.Add(typeof (AType), "Body", ignore);
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BType), overrides);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't alter the library. When I tried the XmlAttributeOverride method, although it ignores the Body tag it also ignores everything below that too. So I end up with just a root node.